# Adding nested data to Firebase with VUEX

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuex

I am having issues getting to store my data for 'players' into my team data. It does save with the team id but i want it to be nested inside of teams.

So I need the players to actually add on and be pusghed onto the empty 'players'...

[image]

My code from my VUEX store pushing to firebase is...

```
 firebase
        .database()
        .ref('teams/')
        .child(payload.id)
        .push(player)
        .then(user => {
          commit('updatePlayers', {
            players: payload.players
          });
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
        });
      // Reach out to firebase and store it      
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it'll work if you put the full path of the reference upfront:

```
firebase.database()
  .ref(`teams/${payload.id}/players`)
  .push(player)
  // .then, .catch, etc.
```